# MudBlazor: how to display notification in Bottom-Right of window?

Tags: mudblazor

I have created an app using MudBlazor template.
All is ok, I use MudBlazor Snackbar and in MainLayout I use
  
and button on it.
On click I call a function

```
ShowNotification("BottomRight")

private void ShowNotification(string position)
{
 Snackbar.Clear();
 Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = position;
 Snackbar.Add(message, Severity.Normal);
}
```

I'd like to show notifications in the Bottom-Right of the Browser window but it displayed in left top corner because it is MudAppBar.
How to display notification in the Bottm-right of browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `"BottomRight"` but `Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomRight` instead:

```cs
@inject ISnackbar Snackbar

<MudButton 
  OnClick="@this.ShowMessage"
  Color="Color.Success">
  Show message
</MudButton>

@code {
    void ShowMessage()
    {
        this.Snackbar.Clear();
        this.Snackbar.Configuration.PositionClass = Defaults.Classes.Position.BottomRight;
        this.Snackbar.Add("Wazzup?", Severity.Normal);
    }
}
```

Demo: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wumnYmbNHjwLplPt